# Markov chain return time $= 1\;/$ equilibrium probability proof

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

After solving [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497006/mean-first-passage-time-of-a-markov-chain/2497316?noredirect=1#comment5158697_2497316), I find that the first-return time, i.e., the diagonal entries of the first-passage time matrix

$$m_{i\rightarrow j}=1+\sum_{k\neq j}P_{i\rightarrow k\,}m_{k\rightarrow j},$$

happen to be the reciprocals of the equilibrium probabilities. The transition probabilities of the sample problem are given by

$$P_{i\rightarrow j}=\begin{pmatrix}
0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0.1 & 0.4\\
0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4
\end{pmatrix}_{\!ij}.$$

I find that the mean first-return times are

$$m_{1\rightarrow 1}=\frac{22}{7},\quad m_{2\rightarrow 2}=4,\quad m_{3\rightarrow 3}=\frac{44}{19},$$

while the equilibrium (invariant) probabilities

$$p_1=\frac{7}{22},\quad p_2=\frac{1}{4},\quad p_3=\frac{19}{44}.$$

The probability $\,p_1+p_2+p_3=1\,$ is normalized and is invariant, i.e.,

$$\sum_ip_iP_{i\rightarrow j}=p_j.$$

I don't think this finding is a coincidence. Mathematically what is the condition for the Markov chain such that $\,m_{i\rightarrow i}=1/p_i\,$ holds for all states $i$?

Comment: The result looks like the mean of a geometric distribution. But Markov chains have short-term memory. Once the initial state $i$ is given, the states afterwards are no longer independent or in equilibrium any more. The $m_{i\rightarrow i}$ and $p_i$ satisfy different recursive relations but are so closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Yes. It is not a coincidence. As you know, the geometric distribution is:

> The probability distribution of the number $X$ of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set $\{ 1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

If the probability of the Bernoulli is $p$, the mean value is $\frac{1}{p}$.

Now you can compare this for a Markov chain with no sink (there is a path from all nodes to others).

For more details and stories you can follow [this](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Ejtc5/251/readings/Basics%20of%20Applied%20Stochastic%20Processes_Serfozo.pdf) and [this](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-MCII.pdf) document.
Also the keyword "Geometric Sojourn Times in a State" can help to follow the context.

Comment: I think the geometric distribution is in the context of repeated independent trials. For Markov chains, the states visited are not like randomly drawn cards with replacement.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe For more details and stories you can follow the referenced documents in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Are there finite-state Markov chains that are null recurrent? I think they should be either positive recurrent or not recurrent at all.